# How to provide constraint to an associative table relating to two source tables with a common foreign key?

Tags: database-design, constraints, data-integrity

Example scenario.

In a flight schedule system, there are a `pilot` table which refers to a `plane_type` table indicating the planes the pilot is able to fly (assuming that is a many-to-one relation).

There are also a `plane` table and it refers to the `plane_type` table to indicate the plane's type
(also many-to-one relation).

Now there is an associative table `flight_plan` which assigns a `pilot` to a `plane` for a given flight.

How do I make sure the `pilot`'s qualification do match the `plane`'s type for this flight?

Any possibility to implement this as a constraint in a database design? Thank you.

**Edited:**

Refering to the diagram below, how to make sure `pilot.plane_type` is equal to `plane.plane_type`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Plane` has unique index (AK) on `PlaneID, PlaneTypeID`

[image]

**EDIT**

```
create table Pilot (PilotID integer);
alter table Pilot add constraint PK_Pilot primary key (PilotID);

create table PlaneType (PlaneTypeID integer);
alter table PlaneType add constraint PK_PlaneType primary key (PlaneTypeID);

create table PilotQualification (PilotID integer, PlaneTypeID integer);
alter table PilotQualification 
  add constraint  PK_PilotQual primary key (PilotID, PlaneTypeID)
, add constraint FK1_PilotQual foreign key (PilotID)     references Pilot(PilotID)
, add constraint FK2_PilotQual foreign key (PlaneTypeID) references PlaneType(PlaneTypeID) ;

create table Plane (PlaneID integer, PlaneTypeID integer);
alter table Plane
  add constraint  PK_Plane primary key (PlaneID)
, add constraint FK1_Plane foreign key (PlaneTypeID) references PlaneType(PlaneTypeID) ;
create unique index AK_Plane on Plane (PlaneID, PlaneTypeID) ;

create table PlanePilot (PlaneID integer, PlaneTypeID integer, PilotID integer) ;
alter table PlanePilot
  add constraint  PK_PlanePilot primary key (PlaneID, PlaneTypeID, PilotID)
, add constraint FK1_PlanePilot foreign key (PilotID, PlaneTypeID) references PilotQualification(PilotID, PlaneTypeID)
, add constraint FK2_PlanePilot foreign key (PlaneID, PlaneTypeID) references Plane(PlaneID, PlaneTypeID)
, add constraint FK3_PlanePilot foreign key (PilotID) references Pilot(PilotID) ;
```

Comment: Isnt this solution just ensures each PlaneType can have only one Plane?

Comment: @CYT NO. Each PlaneType can have many Planes. It assures that Pilot assigned to a Plane has the qualification for that plane. The foreign keys on PLanePilot are FK1 `PlanePilot(PilotID, PlaneTypeID) REFERENCES PilotQualification(PilotID, PlaneTypeID)` and FK2 `PlanePilot(PlaneID, PlaneTypeID) REFERENCES Plane(PlaneID, PlaneTypeID)` and FK3 `PlanePilot(PilotID) REFERENCES Pilot(PilotID)`

Comment: the `PlaneTypeID` in FK1 and `PlaneTypeID` in FK2 is same column in `PlanePilot`?  If not how do the database ensures both column have same value?

Comment: If you restate "Pilot is assigned a [Plane Pilot] Flight Plan" to "**Qualified Pilot** is assigned a Flight Plan" and drop the unnecessary FK between Pilot and PlanePilot, then I'd say this works.