# Database design: multi-path integrity constraints

Tags: database-design, constraints

Consider the following situation: students receive grades for different topics, where *n*-th-year students only attend courses covering *n*-th-year topics. So, we get a commutative "belongs-to" square:

```
 Grades -----> Students
   |             |
   |             |
   v             v
 Topics -----> Levels
```

This is what I mean by "multi-path" in the subject.

(1) What is the technical term for this sort of constraint?

Now add the following data: the topics are grouped into subjects, and there are further data X attached to certain pairs (student, subject), so X is essentially a subset of the cartesian product Students x Subjects. Now the following fact (F) is known: grades always correspond to pairs (student, subject) having a record in X, so we can lift the student foreign keys in the table grades to foreign keys referencing X:

```
 Grades -------> X -------> Students
   |             |
   |             |
   v             v
 Topics ----> Subjects
```

introducing another multi-path constraint (but on the other hand ensuring condition (F)).

(2) What is the theoretical view on these things?

If this is too vague, let me restrict it to the following:

(2') What is the preferred design: the "disjoint" way such that the table grades has foreign keys for students and topics, or the "tight" way of referring to closer table X at the cost of introducing the constaint?

Comment: What exactly is the question? What columns to use for PKs and how to define the FK constraints?

Comment: No. The question is how to deal with constraints which cannot be expressed by simple FK constraints.

Comment: This can be expressed with FK constraints. Whether you consider them as simple or complex, that's another matter.

Comment: And what do you mean with *"at the cost of introducing the constaint?"* You want the constraint to be enforced by the database, don't you?

Comment: By "at the cost", I mean that automatic integrity is preferable to database-enforced integrity. For the rest, see my answer below.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "automatic" integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, for the moment I am content with the solution given in [How to provide constraint to an associative table relating to two source tables with a common foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762485/how-to-provide-constraint-to-an-associative-table-relating-to-two-source-tables)

Summary: add a column level_id to Grades and have multi-column foreign keys (topic_id, level_id) and (student_id, level_id) referencing Topic and Student, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it with the following table design:

a) subject - subjects

b) topics - a list of all available topics, each of which has a FK to subject

c) student - details of the student

d) student_subject - assignment of a subject to a student, additional metadata includes level or class, start date or end date (since a student may repeat)

e) grades - FK to student_subject combination, with additional metadata, date, grade, comments etc ..

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing. I am not certain what you mean by "FK to student_subject": I started with a separate auto_increment PK on student_subject referenced by grades, but this additional level of indirection turned out to be too cumbersome, so I changed student_subject to have a multi-column (student,subject) PK and correspondingly grades having FK to student and subject.

Comment: The separate level of indirection is necessary, because a student may take the same subject in more than one year or they may retake the class so you need to know which particular student-subject combination you need. If you are using a UI you can hide this additional level of redirection